# ARIMAX Forecasting in SPSS vs. R

Tags: r, spss, forecasting, arima, dynamic-regression

I'm using time series data containing both trend and seasonality. I also have 2 endogenous predictor variables that I would like to include in my model.

In R I've used the forecast package to develop a dynamic regression model with use of `auto.arima()` and the `xreg` argument from the `forecast package`. I understand this procedure takes a regression and then attempts to fit the residuals with an ARMA Model.

I've also developed what seems to be an appropriate model using the forecasting Module in SPSS by specifying a Seasonal ARIMA model and including my covariates. However, one of the coefficients on one of my endogeneous predictors has a negative sign which makes no sense intuitively.

I've read Dr. Hyndman's article [The ARIMAX model muddle](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) and found it to be extremely insightful and useful. However, I have not been able to find any documentation on what type of statistical procedure SPSS uses to fit an ARIMA model with covariates, so I'm not sure how I should interpret the coefficients or how concerned I should be with a flipped sign. Any help clarifying the modelling procedure used by SPSS would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: You say *I understand this procedure takes a regression and then attempts to fit the residuals with a linear regression* but that's probably a typo since it is ARMA model that is used to fit the residuals.

Comment: That was a typo; I've updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Algorithms doc available from the Help menu for computational details.  If you have Statistics version 23, you might also be interested in the TCM procedure (Analyze > Forecasting > Create Temporal Causal Models)

Comment: Thank you. It appears as though the series of predictor variables are added to the transfer function model. (I would be interested to know if there is a way to automatically fit an ARMA process to regression residuals as the forecast package in R does.)

I read over some material on Temporal Causal Models and haven't decided if I'll be able to make use of that functionality yet. Thanks for the suggestion.