# How to write the equation for ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0) with exogenous regressors?

Tags: arima

How I should write the equation for this ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,0) based on this SPSS parameter output?

What if it is an ARIMA (0,0,0) or ARIMA (1,0,0) with the same variables?

The independent variables are event variables. I do not know how to fit them into the equation.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps **not** a duplicate of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61510/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-0-2-1-x-0-0-1-period-12?rq=1) or [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-2-1-0-x-0-2-2-period-12?rq=1) since the current one considers exogenous regressors extra to the SARIMA structure.

Comment: I am having some trouble finding what SPSS means by "ARIMAX". Could you point out a detailed manual or help file? See Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) for the alternatives for what "ARIMAX" may stand for. (See also [1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21487479) and especially [**2**](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180217/arimax-forecasting-in-spss-vs-r).)