# auto.arima in R and expert modeller in SPSS not agreeing

Tags: r, time-series, spss, arima, model-selection

I am trying to find the best model for a log return time series.
In SPSS the expert modeller is stating that an ARMA(0,0,0) is the best while in R the best fit is (5,1,0).

Why don't they agree on the same model?

Comment: Why should they agree? There's not a single way to pick ARIMA orders. Everyone does it their own way.

Comment: ARIMA(5,1,0) is a very strange model for log return. Perhaps you made an error when using R?

Comment: @Aksakal I genuinely thought that both use information criteria.

Comment: @RobHyndman why is a strange model? I am looking at the log returns of Bitcoin.

Comment: If the log return is differenced it’s unusual. Log price is differenced

Comment: Log returns would normally be mean-stationary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPSS and `auto.arima()` probably use very different criteria for model selection. `auto.arima()` searches heuristically over the space of possible models, attempting to minimize an information criterion. I don't know how SPSS decides on a model ([but see this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180376/1352)), and I strongly suspect that the algorithm is different - it may minimize one-step ahead forecast errors instead of information criteria, or a different IC than `auto.arima()`, or it may even have the same target function, but iterate through the models differently and end up in a different local optimum.